# Number Pattern Printing

Tags: python

I wish to print these 3 patterns using my code here.

required output -

[image]

However, I'm unable to print these patterns, here is my code -

```
z = 4
for i in range (0,5):
    for j in range(0,i):
        print(" ", end = "")
    for k in range(z, -1, -1):
        print(k, end = "")
    z = z - 1
    print(" ")
```

current output -

[image]

Comment: Small comment: you can use `ljust` and `rjust` methods: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that produces exactly what you want:

```
n = 5
fillchar = ' '    
a = ''.join([str(i) for i in range(0,n)]) # a='01234'

print('\nPattern A:')
for i in range(1,n+1):
    print(a[::-1][-i:n].rjust(n,fillchar))    

print('\nPattern B:')
for i in range(0,n+1):
    print(a[0:i])
    
print('\nPattern C:')
for i in range(0,n+1):
    print(a[0:n-i])
```

And the output:

```
Pattern A:
    0
   10
  210
 3210
43210

Pattern B:
0
01
012
0123
01234

Pattern C:
01234
0123
012
01
0
```

Answer (score 0):

PATTERN - A

```
rows = 6

for row in range(1, rows):

    num = 0

    for j in range(rows, 0, -1):

        if j > row:

            print(" ", end=' ')

        else:

            print(num, end=' ')

            num += 1

    print( )
```

PATTEN -B

```
num = 5
for n in range(0, num):
    for i in range(0, n+1):
        print(i, end=" ")
    print("")
```

PATTERN -c

```
rows = 5

for i in range(rows, 0, -1):

    for j in range(0, i + 1):

        print(j, end=' ')

    print( )
```